# How to put navbar with video background?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, background, nav

I am new to Bootstrap and I have tried to implement a code as `navbar` with video background.

What I have tried:

HTML Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Medical</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/wstyle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="section-header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="images/LOGO.png" style="width:60%" ;>
              </a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                  <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-2 active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-2">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="video-bg">
      <div class="container">
        <video id="video" autoplay loop>
          <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div id="location" class="container">
      <img src="images/image1.PNG" alt="IMAGE" width="100%" height="600px">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have included CSS file(wstyle.css) in folder CSS and video(video.mp4) in video folder.

CSS code as:

CSS (wstyle.css)

```
.video-bg{
  position:fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Now, video is playing different in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome, also video is not playing as background to navbar. How to make video play as background to navbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Something like this.**

```css
    .navigation{
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /** Change value according to you transperncy**/
}

.navbar-right{
  float:right;
  padding-right:10%;
}

.navbar-right a{
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-weight:900;
}

.navbar-right a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
.navbar-logo{
  padding-left:10%;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff; 
}

.video-container {
z-index: -100;
width:100%;
height:75%;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

#video-bg{
  width:100%;
 
}

.portfolio-section{
  margin-top:50%;
}
.tagline-left{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
}

.tagline-right{
  float:right;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
}

.tagline-video{
  width:75%;
}

.tagline-right-text{
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:9%;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:17%;
font-family:Arial;
 color:#fff;
  width:290px;
  font-size:40px;
}

.tagline-left-text{
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:9%;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:11%;
font-family:Arial;
 color:#fff;
  width:375px;
  font-size:40px;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none  !important;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <style>


  </style>

<header>
  <div class="header">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-logo">Logo</a>
      <div class="navbar-right">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="video-container">
      <video autoplay loop muted id="video-bg">

        <source src="//vimeo-hp-videos.global.ssl.fastly.net/3/3.mp4" type="video/mp4">

      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

**Let me know it this is what you want**

Comment: let me know if you want something else :)

Comment: This displays text with video background , I want navigation bar with video as background

Comment: wait for a minute.

Comment: Is it responsive?

Comment: now check, I updated my Code and yes it is responsive, Don't forget to verify my answer if this will work for you.

Comment: Let me know if you want anything else.

Comment: This navigation is at the top . I want a transparent navigation with video as background. I want to play video while navigating menus

Comment: very first I code for transparent then you want this kind of navbar.

Comment: can you share a screenshot of output what you want?

Comment: @ Nishant Can you please share the code implemented first with transparent navigation with menus .That is actually I want.

Comment: you mean dropdown menu?

Comment: Check again I updated my code I think this is what you want.